# Ssr на Next.js и php

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, nextjs, ssr

Я fullstack на react и php. Хочу решить проблему с ssr. Next.js - прекрасное решение, но можно ли с ним нормально работать с php? Стоит ли вообще учить next.js для работы с php? Или вы знаете какое-нибдуь решение проблемы с ssr для react и php?

Comment: А какое отношение имеет SSR к PHP ? Эта технология в принципе была придумана, что бы решить проблему создания на сервере той же страницы с которой на клиенте работает JS. Следовательно и серверный код должен быть написан на JS. А отсюда следует что на сервере оно работать под node.js. Отсюда вопрос, зачем вам вообще нужен PHP, если JS вы знаете, а код под node.js точно такой же. Вот и пишите на одном языке все

Comment: @Mike Опять сказки про "пишите всё на JS")) Ну нельзя всё под одно, у всего разные области применения и производительность.

Comment: Но вообще да. SSR и PHP (как API) - это вообще про разное. SSR всего лишь рендерит страничку как на клиенте, чтобы SEO было нормальное (ну и иногда пользователи по минуте не ждали прогрузки). А что PHP - ну что-то на бэке сделал, выплюнул данные, дальше делайте с ними что хотите. Клиенту на react/vue/angular/[подставить что хочется] всё равно как там на бэке всё устроено, для клиента бэк - черный ящик.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Почему сказки, если нужен полноценный SSR, то эта часть бека на JS. Я с этой точки зрения писал. Никто не мешает при этом быть еще rest беку на другом языке, если требуется задачей

Comment: Ну вообще я писал полгода назад большое приложение на vue + laravel. И там к laravel кое-как прикрутил какой-то сервис, который для поисковых роботов выполнял js код и возвращал готовый html. Это работало плохо, но всё же ssr через laravel)